# Export single table data from SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a large sql server database(2012 express) which I was working on. In it, there is a lot of test data. Now, for some reason, I have to use a different pc. I dont want to export ALL the data in the db, just from this one table that I was working on. I scripted the schema to a file(the table was created on the local previous machine) and I ran it on the new pc. However, I need a way to export the data.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install this tools pack http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/ you can then right click the table and under the SSMS tools option you'll find an option to script the table to a new query window.

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543132/1073262) uses tools built into SQLMS if you'd rather not use a commercial product.