# How can I export tables to SQL Script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to export many tables to Script SQL.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please clarify? Do you need to export table names, schema, creation scripts, data....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542819/how-to-export-all-data-from-table-to-an-insertable-sql-format

This should be marked duplicate

Comment: I need to export DDL and Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Right** click on the database

2) Go to **Tasks -> Generate Scripts**

3) A **Generate and Publish script** popup window will appear. Click **Next**

4) Select **specific database objects**. And select **Tables**

5) Go To **Adanced**, another popup window will be displayed. Scroll down to **Types of data script** and select **Schema and Data**

6) And then **Save to file or clipboard** and click **Next**

Comment: I need to export DDL and Data.  This export only the DDL.

Answer (score 1):

1) Simple Right Click on **Database name** in object explorer,

2) menu list will be open then from this list go to Task  in **Task** sub menu Click on **Generate Script**

3) A New Dailog will be opened click on **Next button**

4) select the **tables and any DDL name** which you want  then click next

5) Then **choose path** where you save script click next