# Print UPDATE statement for a row based on select results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select-query

I have a scenario where there is Prod/Test and in the Test environment, I have a settings table (row) with many columns that I'd like to be able to run an `UPDATE` after a database refresh and set everything back.

This select would return a row of columns I want to preserve.

`select * from mysettings a where a.company = 'abc'`

Is there a way to dynamically take this result and output something like this:

```
UPDATE mysettings
    set field1 = 'some str',
        field2 = 2,
        field3 = 234234,
        field4 = '2016-08-23 18:51:42.000',
        ...
    where mysettings.company = 'abc'
```

The reason I say Dynamically is I have different companies and environments, and also some fields are `strings`, `int`, `datetime`, etc and the goal is to save this script off as a final "step" to perform.

**EDIT:** Similar to this method, except instead of `INSERT` I want `UPDATE`.

[How to export all data from table to an insertable sql format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542819/how-to-export-all-data-from-table-to-an-insertable-sql-format)

Comment: Are you asking can we convert results of select into an update?

Comment: Basically. So that I can update the same row with the original data. I am wanting to save it off to a *.sql file to run later. So not update from a select, because it's the same row and same table.

Comment: Does this help? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Comment: just back it up and use merge perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
SELECT 'UPDATE mysettings 
SET field1 = ''' + mysettings.field1 + ''',
SET field2 = ''' + mysettings.field2 + ''',
...
WHERE mysettings.company = ''' + @company_name + ''''
FROM mysettings WHERE mysettings.compnay = @company_name
```

Comment: I think so, but I'd need the `SET` lines dynamically created

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will work

```
--Declare SelectQuery variable
     declare @selectQuery varchar(max);
--Set Query 
        set selectQuery ='select  * from  mysettings where  where mysettings.company ='abc'+';
            UPDATE mysettings
                set field1 = 'some str',
                    field2 = 2,
                    field3 = 234234,
                    field4 = '2016-08-23 18:51:42.000',
                    ...
                where mysettings.company = 'abc'
        --Printing the Query
          print   @selectQuery
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVlJq.png Click to Show result

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Is it the correct answer you are expected?

Comment: Kindly check the below answer I have been added.

Comment: Please don’t do this. In normal situations, you should only post one answer to a thread. If you find a better approach, or correct a mistake, you should [edit] your answer with the preferred update. If you must suggest distinctly different answers as different posts, please include an explanation for each of what sets it apart, and when or why it might be preferred over your other approaches. If you can’t do that, consider deleting the answers.