# SQL Server's Export Wizard converts nvarchar(200) to LongText instead of ShortText

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssms

I need to migrate some tables from SQL Server to database on another server, but those 2 servers are not in available in the same network.

I decided to use SSMS's Export Wizard to export data from source server to MS Access, and then, after switching networks, to import data from this Access file to destination server.

I had some problems with tables definitions so I scripted all the tables as `CREATE` script and ran it on the destination server, this way tables are exactly the same on both source & destination server.

The problem is that, when exporting to MS Access file, SSMS converts any `nvarchar` to `LongText`, even if it's limited `nvarchar` e.g. `nvarchar(200)`.

This alone probably isn't problematic, but when you try to import data to destination server, I'm getting errors (even though I set it to ignore errors) and the process stops. The problem is that the columns in Access is `LongText` and in destination's server it's `nvarchar(200)`. When I change the column type in Access to `ShortText`, everything works correctly.

I would probably go table after table and change all `LongText` to `ShortText` (where source type is a length limited `nvarchar`), but I checked and there are around 100 of such columns. I checked LongText vs ShortText on MS docs and it reads ShortText is below 255 characters and LongText is everything above, so I'm puzzled why SSMS converts every `nvarchar` (even those below 255) to LongText. You would think those technologies should talk well to each other as they both are Microsoft's but no no. Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: I'd rather stay in SQL Server, using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542819/how-to-export-all-data-from-table-to-an-insertable-sql-format

Comment: You could also use bcp.  It will give you more control over formatting if you really need it.

Comment: @Andre Great tip, haven't realised there is a way to script data insert! It took a whlile to create scripts for all the data but it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertSievers As to backup, the source server is extremly locked, meaning it's difficult to move the backup file from source server, unless you physically put a flashdrive in

Comment: @robs23  If you can access the server via SSMS, you can do so with bcp.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @RobertSievers I didn't know this tool at all. Sounds interesting, need to read up on it a bit. Thanks!